# How can I set the schema name used by hibernate entities at query time?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

Our application uses Hibernate for ORM, and stores data in several schemas, accessing them with a user whose grants are customized for the application.

The schema names are determined at runtime based on data; it's not feasible to include their names in the entity mapping documents.  This means that I need a way to tell Hibernate to use a specific schema name when performing lookups.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a page that lists some ways you can manage [multiple schemas in Hibernate](http://web.archive.org/web/20071011173719/http://hibernate.org/429.html).  I'd probably go with implementing your own [connection provider](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/connection/ConnectionProvider.html).  You'll probably want to disable caching as well.

Comment: One of the perils of the internet I suppose.  I've updated the links as best I can.

Answer (score 1):

We ran into this problem at work. I fixed it, as Robert suggests, by creating a connection provider (ie, an implementation of DataSource), called ""OracleSchemaRemappingDataSource" and using spring to do the plumbing.

Basically, this datasource implements getConnection(). The implementation of that method works by getting a connection from some other data source by spring injection, which it assumes to be an oracle connection, and then executing

```
ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = 'someotherschema'
```

and them passing that connection back.

All of the hibernate config is careful to use names without specifying schemas for them.

Also: with this, you don't want to disable caching - allow hibernate to manage connections as normal, as we are not doing any magic within the app such as using different connections on a per-user basis.

Comment: Do you think your solution could be adapted to work when multiple schemas are accessed in the course of a transaction?  Obviously it could work if there were _two_ schemas -- one fixed, and the other dependent on the situation.  I'll be contacting you, however.  Thanks!

Comment: Well, if your setup is this weird, another way to do it is to create oracle table aliases for each of the user names that you log on as. It's a lot of management, of course. Or you can combine the solutions = use CURRENT_SCHEMA and also have schemas with table aliases pointng to other schemas.