# Can I change the schema in execution time with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, orm, multi-tenant

I have an application where before save any data has to select the schema in a database running on PostgreSQL. How can I do this with Hibernate?

This is because there are different users that use the same application, but the data is separated in one schema per user.

Comment: That seems like terrible design.

Comment: Why says that? There is my implementation of a multi-tenant application

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398215/how-can-i-set-the-schema-name-used-by-hibernate-entities-at-query-time