# Hibernate doesn't include schema into query

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, schema, oracle-sqldeveloper

According to configuration, Hibernate DAO repository should send query like this:

```
INSERT INTO some_schema.some_table (...) VALUES (...)
```

Instead, Hibernate sends this:

```
INSERT INTO some_table (...) VALUES (...)
```

It omits schema prefix. Without that prefix I am getting ORA-00942, table does not exist Oracle database error. How to force Hibernate send schema prefix?

**P.S.** This question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737420/how-to-set-up-default-schema-name-in-jpa-configuration), but adding default schema doesn't work for me, because I am using more of them.

Configuration of entity is like this:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.somepackage.SomeClass" table="some_table" schema="some_schema">
  <id name="someID" type="int" column="SOME_TABLE_ID">
     <generator class="increment"/>
  </id>
  <property name="someProp" column="SOME_PROP" type="string"/>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Hibernate config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<!-- Oracle data source definition -->
<bean id="oracleDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName"><value>${oracle.database.driverClassName}</value></property>
    <property name="url"><value>${oracle.database.url}</value></property>
    <property name="username"><value>${oracle.database.username}</value></property>
    <property name="password"><value>${oracle.database.password}</value></property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="oracleDataSource" />
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>some-table.cfg.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Please show your hibernate configuration file

Comment: @SatishPahuja here is the hibernate config.

Answer (score 2):

Add the below in your hibernate properties. It should automatically be picked. I have the same and it works

```
<property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="myschema"/>
```

Comment: Also found the below link which refers to the same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737420/how-to-set-up-default-schema-name-in-jpa-configuration

Comment: Thanks for answer! But I shouldn't set default_schema because application will in some moment use more schema's.

Comment: Have no experience with that but did some search  and came up with the below link , see if that helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398215/how-can-i-set-the-schema-name-used-by-hibernate-entities-at-query-time